# Logarithmic shell expansion?

Tags: bash, scripts

I know there is ** for exponentiation in bash. Is there a simple shell expansion for logarithms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You'll have to call out to an external program.

```
$ echo 'l(10)' | bc -l
2.30258509299404568401
```

Comment: is this part of echo? can someone provide explanation in how / why that works? Or even just more detail? I tried bc -l l(10) and got errors.

Comment: you have to pass the expression that `bc -l` will evaluate on `bc`'s stdin. `echo` is just echoing characters, nothing more. Then `bc` reads the expression `l(10)` from its stdin channel and calculates the answer. Another way to write this, using the bash here-string, is `bc -l <<< "l(10)"`